# Steven King's Cell Novel

Tags: novel, stephen-king

I made it about half way through Steven King's Cell novel and I ended up losing my copy and never finishing it. I understand that the film will be released this year. Does the book ever reveal the source of the signal? It's been on my mind recently. Appologies for any spoilers. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: @DaveJohnson no, the source of the signal is not revealed. There are some theories of the characters, but nothing is clealry explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have the book handy, though I will try to get more details later.  However, it is revealed that

> The cell signal is the work of terrorists.  We also find out that they just wanted to destabilize the world a bit, not turn it into an actual dystopia.  Something went wrong, though I do not recall what, exactly.

Comment: This was only a guess by one of the characters, we never find out if they were right or not.

Comment: @Liesmith I do not have the book anymore (just looked), but I distinctly remember a scene in which we meet the scientists responsible.  I may have to buy the Kindle version just for this....